# How to set the curved line color in line chart MPAndroid chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have tried to change the curve color and circle color of the following line chart with

```
dataset.setColor()

dataset.setCircleColor()
```

in MPAndroid chart.

[image]

Here is how I set my chart:

```
final LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(chart_entries, "Product Sale Graph"); 
lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_chart_gradient);
lineDataSet.setFillDrawable(drawable);
lineDataSet.setCircleColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
lineDataSet.setColor(R.color.colorAccent);
```

Comment: Have you tried that: val vl = LineDataSet(entries, "My Type"); vl.color = R.color.custom_color (Kotlin). Because, for example, I set needed colours like so <-- in my project and they're represented correctly

Comment: I couldn't find any attribute named color. Maybe its private and thats why setter getter is usued.

Comment: could you please be so kind to prove a code snippet of how you set your chart?

Comment: Here it is:
final LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(chart_entries, "Product Sale Graph");
lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_chart_gradient);
lineDataSet.setFillDrawable(drawable);
lineDataSet.setCircleColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
lineDataSet.setColor(R.color.colorAccent);